# Python Pulp - Number of Unique Teams Constraint

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am new to Pulp and therefore have been encountering a problem when trying to make a conditional constraint. I have made a fantasy football optimizer that picks the optimal selection of 9 players, my solver fully works currently with position constraints, salary constraints, and more.

The last thing I need to add is a constraint that makes it so out of the 9 players it picks, there need to be 8 unique team names of the players. For example: there is a Quarterback and a WR/TE going to be on the same team given this constraint in my code `###Stack QB with 2 teammates`. and therefore everyone else should be on a different team than each other to have 8 unique team names.

Below is the the code i have tried to use to make this constraint, the head of the excel file being optimized and my code that works so far without the constraint I want to add of 8 unique team names in the 9 players selected.

I have currently tried this but it doesn't work! Would really appreciate any help!

```
list_of_teams = raw_data['Team'].unique()
team_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('team', list_of_teams, cat = 'Binary')

for team in list_of_teams:
  prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Team'][i] == team] + [-9*team_vars[team]]) <= 0

prob += pulp.lpSum([team_vars[t] for t in list_of_teams]) >= 8
```

[image: CSV File with player data]

```
file_name = 'C:/Users/Michael Arena/Desktop/Football/Simulation.csv'
raw_data = pd.read_csv(file_name,engine="python",index_col=False, header=0, delimiter=",", quoting = 3)


player_ids = raw_data.index
player_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('player', player_ids, cat='Binary')

prob = pulp.LpProblem("DFS Optimizer", pulp.LpMaximize)

prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Projection'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids])

##Total Salary upper:
prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Salary'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) <= 50000

##Total Salary lower:
prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Salary'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) >= 49900

##Exactly 9 players:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) == 9

##2-3 RBs:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'RB']) >= 2
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'RB']) <= 3

##1 QB:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'QB']) == 1
##3-4 WRs:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'WR']) >= 3
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'WR']) <= 4

##1-2 TE's:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'TE']) >= 1
# prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'TE']) <= 2

##1 DST:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'DST']) == 1


###Stack QB with 2 teammates
for qbid in player_ids:
    if raw_data['Position'][qbid] == 'QB':
        prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if 
                          (raw_data['Team'][i] == raw_data['Team'][qbid] and 
                            raw_data['Position'][i] in ('WR', 'TE'))] + 
                            [-1*player_vars[qbid]]) >= 0

###Don't stack with opposing DST:
for dstid in player_ids:
    if raw_data['Position'][dstid] == 'DST':
        prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if
                            raw_data['Team'][i] == raw_data['Opponent'][dstid]] +
                            [8*player_vars[dstid]]) <= 8



###Stack QB with 1 opposing player:
for qbid in player_ids:
    if raw_data['Position'][qbid] == 'QB':
        prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if
                            (raw_data['Team'][i] == raw_data['Opponent'][qbid] and 
                            raw_data['Position'][i] in ('WR', 'TE'))]+
                            [-1*player_vars[qbid]]) >= 0


prob.solve()
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Linear Programming terms**

Let `x_i = 1` if the `i^th` player is chosen, and 0 otherwise, `i = 1....I`.
Let `t_i` be the team of the `i^th` player, which is a constant.
Let `t_j` be the `j^th` unique team, also a constant, `j = 1....T`.
And let `t_{ij} = 1` if `t_i == t_j`, and 0 otherwise. This is also a constant.

Then you can say that the total number of players selected from team `t_j` is `(t_{1j}*x_1 + t_{1j}*x_2 + ... + t_{Ij}*x_I)`, which takes a value between 0 and I, logically.

---

Now, you can let the binary variable `y_j = 1` if any selected players come from team `t_j`, and 0 otherwise, like this:

```
(t_{1j}*x_1 + t_{1j}*x_2 + ... + t_{Ij}*x_I) >= y_j
```

This gives you the following situation:

- If `(t_{1j}*x_1 + t_{1j}*x_2 + ... + t_{Ij}*x_I) = 0`, then `y_j` is 0;
- If `(t_{1j}*x_1 + t_{1j}*x_2 + ... + t_{Ij}*x_I) > 0`, then `y_j` can be 0 or 1.

And now, if you add a constraint `(y_1 + y_2 + ... + y_T) >= 8`, that implies that `(t_{1j}*x_1 + t_{1j}*x_2 + ... + t_{Ij}*x_I) > 0` for at least 8 different teams `t_j`.

---

**In PULP terms** (something like this, wasn't able tot test it)

If `player_vars` is a binary variable equivalent to `x_i`

```py
teams = raw_data['Team']  # t_i
unique_teams = teams.unique()  # t_j
player_in_team = teams.str.get_dummies()  # t_{ij}

# Example output for `teams = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'E'])`:
#    A  B  C  D  E  F
# 0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 1  0  1  0  0  0  0
# 2  0  0  1  0  0  0
# 3  0  0  0  1  0  0
# 4  0  0  0  0  1  0
# 5  0  0  0  0  0  1
# 6  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 7  0  0  1  0  0  0
# 8  0  0  0  0  1  0

team_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('team', unique_teams, cat='Binary')  # y_j

for team in unique_teams:
  prob += pulp.lpSum(
      [player_in_team[team][i] * player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]
  ) >= team_vars[team]

prob += pulp.lpSum([team_vars[t] for t in unique_teams]) >= 8
```

Comment: First off I want to say, thank you for taking the time to read and respond to my question. I really appreciate it. I’m still pretty confused when looking at your code right now though (I am not the most advanced coder). Would you be able to put out the solution of code I would need to implement? Would make it easier for me to follow along with how it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: I've added a Python implementation, but I wasn't able to test it. Hope it helps you wrap your mind around it

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to implement it, I wanted to see if it worked and then understand it but I'm getting some errors with the code. in the `for team in unique_teams` loop I am getting a NameError as `i` is not defined. and for the `for team in team_vars` loop I'm getting a syntax issue that I cant figure out how to fix. Any corrections or suggestions to me would be really appreciated

Comment: Hi Ruben, I've been trying many different ways to make this code work and I've been struggling to make it happen. Would really appreciate a follow up!

Comment: Awesome! I got it working now, i really appreciate your help!!! really nice of you to take the time. All the best